# Creating subclass instances from base class constructor

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor

I am learning about OOP with Java. Say I have a base class Car with subclasses that extend Car called Engine, FuelTank and Wheels. Is it possible to instantiate these extended classes from the base class of Car so that each instance of car will have its own instance of each subclass?

```
class Car{
      Car(){
          // instance of Engine
          // instance of Wheels
          // instance of FuelTank
      }
 }

class CarPart{}

class Engine extends CarPart{}

class Wheels extends CarPart{}

class FuelTank extends CarPart{}
```

Comment: It makes no sense for these classes to extend Car.

Comment: It is possible. What's the problem?

Comment: What would the the correct way to create an instance of each subclass in the constructor? Can the base class call subclass methods?

Comment: Any class that extends Car should itself be (in some sense) a Car. I don't think an Engine, Wheels or Fuel Tank are a kind of Car. Look at Oracle's own explanation of this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html

Comment: write the class keeping the coherence of the nature you are modeling, ask yourself the question: ***is an engine a kind of car?*** if yes, then it would make sense doing ***Engine extends Car***

Comment: calling methods is only one way, UP. you can only call methods of superclasses, not subclasses. That is, unless you instantiate the object as the subclass initially.

Comment: ok so I added a CarPart class and made these parts extend CarPart. Can the Car class still create an instance of each subclass of CarPart?

Comment: sure can.......

Comment: First you need to understand what is inheritance and where you need it. One good reference has provided by the @Chrs. Then draw a inheritance tree in peace of paper diciding what should be in the each and every class. However, if it is possible or not, it doesnt make any sense of instantitating subclasses in its superclass.

Comment: Now you have updated the question. so according to updated example it is posible. However read that oracle tutorial

Comment: @Eran That's not the important part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is:

***Inside a class, can I create instances of other classes?***

Well, theoretical and technical, you can easily receive the answer "yes". But the real answer is... "no". Because, if you do it:

- you are tightly coupling the class **in which** the instances are created (`Car`) to the classes **from which** the instances are created (`Engine`, `Wheels`, `FuelTank`). This way, a car will always must have a fuel tank, even though there could be implemented an electrical power only solution.
- the car will not only have the responsibility to go on a road, but to create its car parts by itself, too. And this is somehow... "Transformers"-like.

But, if you want to correctly learn and apply OOP, then these two situations are not a "permitted" option. It's the same as: in a normal swimming competition you **could** use a pair of fins, but you would be desqualified.

That said, the only viable alternative to **tight coupling** is the **loose coupling**: the car parts are injected, e.g. passed, e.g. plugged into the car. In OOP, this process has the name **dependency injection** (DI). The car parts - the **dependencies** - can then be easily changed, or removed. So, the fuel tank can then be completely removed, because the car will be driven only with electrical power. The car itself has now the single responsibility of going on a road. And, even if it still depends on its parts - as it should, the car is not anymore concerned with the process of car parts creation: it just receives them - as it should.

I just realised, that I'd use another conceptual scheme: an `Engine` should not be a `CarPart`. Only the fact that it's plugged into a car makes it a car part. The same goes for the `Wheels` and `FuelTank`. In short, I'd define them in other way:

```
class Engine {...}
class Wheels {...}
class FuelTank {...}

class CarEngine extends Engine {...}
class CarWheels extends Wheels {...}
class CarFuelTank extends FuelTank {...}
```

So, the loose coupling will be applied like this:

```
class Car{

    Car(instance of CarEngine, instance of CarWheels, instance of CarFuelTank){
        //...
    }

}
```

or, even better, in analogy with your code version:

```
class Car {

    Car(instance of Engine, instance of Wheels, instance of FuelTank){
        //...
    }

}
```

Here are two wonderful resources for a better understanding of the principles presented here:

- **[The Clean Code Talks - Don't Look For Things!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0)**
- **[Slutty Software is good software: Tight and loose coupling in
  OOP](https://r.je/slutty-software-tight-and-loose-coupling.html)**

Good luck with your projects!

---

### EDIT 1:

@Ryan The Leach kindly and rightly proposed me to also present you the notion/concept of **factory**. I'll try to do it in a principle manner.

The car needs an engine to be able to function. But who could produce this car part? Well: an engine factory. More precisely a car engine factory.

In terms of OOP, a **factory** is a specialized class having a single responsibility: the **creation of instances of other classes** (sounds familiar?). The created instances are then used somewhere else, according with their usefulness. Now, when a factory creates an object, or more objects of different class types, it may need to gather/produce other resources too, in order to prepare the creation of the final "product(s)".

So, an engine factory would first need to gather/produce a lot of engine pieces before assembling/creating the final engine. The same applies to a car factory: it needs to receive an engine from the engine factory, wheels from the wheels factory and a fuel tank from the fuel tanks factory. Then it produces the final cars.

In OOP, there are three types of factories, e.g of so called *factory patterns*:

- The **simple factory**
- The **factory method** and
- The **abstract factory**.

I'll not present them here personally, but I'll try to direct you to some (very) good web resources, easy to follow and understand:

- **[Factory Method Pattern – Head First Design Patterns (ep 04)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcFVTgRHJLM&index=4&list=PLrhzvIcii6GNjpARdnO4ueTUAVR9eMBpc)**
- **[Abstract Factory Pattern – Head First Design Patterns (ep 05)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-GiuMmsXj4&list=PLrhzvIcii6GNjpARdnO4ueTUAVR9eMBpc&index=5)**
- **[Abstract Factory Design Pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbjAsdAK4xQ)**
- **[Abstract Factory Design Pattern...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSbORGBLMjY)** (There is a very good sheme in regard of using the pattern for assembling and creating a database connection)
- **[Factory Method vs Abstract Factory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4m7IuLM4wdw)** (Very understandable diagrams)

P.S:

The first two are my favorites... although I didn't watched them yet :-) Yes, silly, isn't it? Because they are relative new uploads I didn't knew that they exist. BUT: I followed all the other streams of the author and, in three words: I was impressed. Nota bene: the author explains all the patterns presented in the book "*Head First Design Patterns*".

Comment: You should probably show OP factory methods as well.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for this feedback!

Comment: @Kisner You are welcome. Just added somethhing more about factories (a fundamental OOP pattern, which you'll use overall and all times). Good luck.

Comment: @Kisner I missed to present you something: the car MUST have a single responsibility: to go on a road. This "**single responsibility**" is in fact a very important principle, as part of the so-called  **S.O.L.I.D. principles** in OOP. Please search for **Robert C. Martin (or Uncle Bob)**, the famous founder of them. Here is one link of many more: [Robert C Martin - The Single Responsibility Principle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gt0M_OHKhQE). Bye and thank you for the appreciation.

Answer (score 2):

From Syntax point of view , yes you can declare and create the instances of child class in Parent base class as below.

```
public class Base {
     public void someMethod(){
         Child child1 = new Child(); // valid
         Base child2 = new Child(); // valid
    }
}

public class Child extends Base{

}
```

Good Practices and OOPs design point of view : You should not create objects of child class in base class.

You should inherit a class `B` from `A` only when `B` **behaves** like `A` with some additional behaviors.

Usually it happens the Base class is written befor the child sub classes. While writing the Base Class you can not know in future which classes and how many classes are going to extend it. You should practice not modifying the existing class (its called Open closed principle). Of course requirements gets refined, redefined and result in refactoring the classes or design. Its a principle, a guideline, you need not follow it too strictly but always keep it in mind and when ever you voilate it you must have a **very good reason** to do so. 
Inheritence itself is not a very good prqctice as it exposes a internals of parent class to the child class. Its often called as white box reuse. It breaks encapsulation in a way. For this purpose you should favor `composition` over `inheritence`.

In your case your `Car` class should have instance reference fields for the object of `Wheel`, `Engine` etc.

If you want to add more flexibility to your code you can go one step ahead and define interfaces for `Wheel`, `Engine` and then have your class `Car` depend only upon these interfaces. This will protect you in case tomorrow you decide to add new variety of `Wheel` (like NormalWheel , AlloyWheel) or you decide to create the car instance with inhanced different implementation of engine, then these classes can just confirm to the defined interfaces and the concrete objects of the required Engine or Wheel can be *injected* in `Car` class.  Depending upon interfaces rather than concrete class protects you from modification of already tested and stable code later.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider your **Car** example.

Base class should be a general form of what you select as the class.It should not be specific.

Extended class or Sub class should be a specific version base class. If Car is your base class, then your sub classes should be **SportCar**, **Taxi**, **RacingCar** etc.

For example, **SportCar** is a specific version of **Car** which has more features which are specific to it's task.

There should be a **Is-A Relationship** between sub class and base class.

**"Sub class" is a "Base calss"**.

Hope this will be helpful......

Comment: So Engine, wheels and fuel tank are car parts, or is this too generic? Perhaps these classes should be their own base class?

Comment: You can say Engine, wheels and fuel tank are sub classes of car parts. It is perfectly fine. When you are developing a program, if there are some classes with common features or behaviors, make a base class using them.

Comment: Not always **is a relation** implies inheritance. Consider the example of **Square is a Rectangle** Try researching why here inheriting Square from Rectangle is a bad idea. [hint a graphic application has rectangle and rectangles are used in a canvas area with defined width and height. Here if square are used polymorphically in place of rectangle being sub class of rectangle, now user tries to alter the height , what will happen ..? ]

Comment: OK. There are some special cases. We **Rectangle** may have two methods to alter height and width independently. But **Square** class should not alter them independently. But it is still possible with some simple coding.

Comment: with that simple coding you need to take care of following the principles : empty body method - a bad practice, a method just throwing an exception - a bad practice. A sub class should be a perfect substitute for its base class. Each method invocation must follow whats been promised by the method declaration in base class (LSP in S.O.*L*.I.D)